# Set Fluent Validator by condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to set validator for `Address` depends on item existence, but I wanna use RuleFor and other handy methods rather that manually log every error with `ValidationContext` but it seems like when I'm trying to do it via `CustomAsync`, it's just skipped and rules for `RequestAddressValidator` skipped.

Do you have any ideas on how to make RequestAddressValidator rules working?

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public required string Id { get; init; }

    public Address? Address { get; init; }
}

public class Address
{
    public required string Line1 { get; init; }
    public required string Line2 { get; init; }
}

public class RequestAddressValidator: AbstractValidator<Address>
{
    public RequestAddressValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Line1).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.Line2).NotEmpty();
    }
}

public class RequestModelValidator: AbstractValidator<RequestModel>
{
    public RequestModelValidator(IApiClient apiClient)
    {
        RuleFor(x => x)
            .Custom((requestModel, context) =>
            {
                var item = apiClient.GetByIdAsync(requestModel.Id);

                if (item != null)
                {
                    RuleFor(x => x.Address).SetValidator(new RequestAddressValidator());
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `CustomAsync` and await that `apiClient.GetByIdAsync` call.

See [asynchronous validation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/async.html)

```
public class RequestModelValidator: AbstractValidator<RequestModel>
{
    public RequestModelValidator(IApiClient apiClient)
    {
        RuleFor(x => x)
            .CustomAsync(async (requestModel, context, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                var item = await apiClient.GetByIdAsync(requestModel.Id);

                if (item != null)
                {
                    RuleFor(x => x.Address).SetValidator(new RequestAddressValidator());
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Also pay attention to the notices on that page, especially the one about the automatic validation with ASP.NET.

Since you have this question tagged with `ASP.NET` and you are using asynchronous validation, you need to use [manual validation](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/aspnet.html#manual-validation); making that `validator.ValidateAsync` call yourself.

> If your validator contains asynchronous validators or asynchronous conditions, it’s important that you always call `ValidateAsync` on your validator and never `Validate`. If you call Validate, then an exception will be thrown.

> You should not use asynchronous rules when using automatic validation with ASP.NET as ASP.NET’s validation pipeline is not asynchronous.